# .Net MVC to to add html attributes using @HTMLTextAreaFor

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having trouble adding some html attributes to a text area when using the @HTML command. I am just trying to add a class name, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "required-field" } })
```

and it is generating:

```
<textarea id="Message" rows="2" name="Message" htmlattributes="{ class = required-field }" data-val-required="The Message field is required." data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>
```

I am not sure why it is displaying htmlattributes="{ class = required-field }" instead of class="required-field" as the same code works fine for normal text inputs - i.e. 
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "required-field" } })`

works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Its just `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "required-field" })`

Comment: Thanks, that works great - any idea why it is different for textarea than editor?

Comment: `EditorFor()` is a special case (and until MVC-5.1 you could not even add html attributes using `EditorFor()`) because you could have a custom `EditorTemplate` with multiple elements so the values are passed to the template as additional `ViewData`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stephen Muecke
"Its just @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "required-field" })"